# Button not functioning properly in java applet, function only on minimization or maximization

Tags: java, button, applet, awt

In the following program the button is not functioning properly. It only fuctions if the given applet generated by the code is maximized or minimized. Basically I want that the shapes should be generated by clicking the "draw" button but if it is clicked the shapes are not generated. They are generated only when after pressing the button the applet is minimized or maximized.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Fig extends Applet implements ActionListener{

    TextField cir,sq,recw,rech;
    Button b;
    int r,s,w,h;
    
    public void init(){
        
        Label rad=new Label("Radius of circle");
        cir=new TextField(8);
        Label squ=new Label("Side of square");
        sq=new TextField(8);
        Label rectw=new Label("Width of rectangle");
        recw=new TextField(8);
        Label recth=new Label("Height of rectangle");
        rech=new TextField(8);
        add(rad); add(cir); add(squ); add(sq); add(rectw); add(recw); add(recth); add(rech);
        b=new Button("Draw");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        add(b);
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        
        r=Integer.parseInt(cir.getText());
        s=Integer.parseInt(sq.getText());
        w=Integer.parseInt(recw.getText());
        h=Integer.parseInt(rech.getText());
    
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        
        g.drawRect(20,60,w,h);
        g.drawOval(200,120,r,r);
        g.drawRect(20,200,s,s);
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not use applets. It is outdated technology.

Comment: Applets are _completely_ dead.

Comment: I know, but I cannot understand the error in the code. Could you please tell me?